How to resolve the error nothing injectable for the binding name when using Pinject
I'm getting this error when trying to compile my Python code using Pinject:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pinject/bindings.py", line 133, in get
    raise errors.NothingInjectableForArgError(
pinject.errors.NothingInjectableForArgError: when injecting Foo.__init__ at /src/grpc/services/foo_manager/foo_manager_service.py:35, nothing injectable for the binding name "get_my_foo_by_bar_query_handler" (unannotated)

I'm using pinject v0.14.1
This is how I'm initializing the class:
    def __init__(self,
                 get_my_foo_by_bar_query_handler: GetMyFOOBarQueryHandler) -> None:
        self._get_my_foo_by_bar_query_handler = get_my_foo_by_bar_query_handler

Tried to compile, but it throws the error

I've never heard of the project, but after a little research, it appears that Pinject is deprecated by the authors (Google) .. can you add some more about what you're tring to do? this Issue (created now over 5 years ago) also suggests that even the basic example(s) don't work https://github.com/google/pinject/issues/38
